# convert two chars at a time from a string to hex

Tags: string, perl, hex

I have the following piece of code which converts 1 char to a hex at a time. I want to convert two chars to a hex. ie 99ab should be treated as '99', 'ab' to be converted to its equivalent hex.

Current implementation is as follows

```
$final =~ s/(.)/sprintf("0x%X ",ord($1))/eg;
chop($final);
```

TIA

Comment: Your question is not clear. What should `$final` contain if it started with `$final = "99ab";`?

Comment: @ikegami: I think he wants to treat them in two byte segments

Comment: isn't 99ab already hex?

Comment: @xxaxxon: ord converts the character into its ASCII value.

Comment: @0A0D, Yes, he said he wants to take two at a time. That part is clear. My question is about determining what should be done with the char pairs once they're obtained. (He said he wants to convert the pair to hex, which makes no sense. You can only convert numbers to hex, not strings of two characters. I almost think he wants to convert *from* hex, but his code has him attempting to convert something *to* hex.)

Comment: Sorry was away. I guess the question is little ambiguous. I want to get ascii equivalent of each char, then have two chars in a row with their ascii values and convert that to hex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question doesn't make much sense. Hex is a string representation of a *number*. You can't convert a *string* to hex.

You can convert individual *characters* of a string to hex since characters are merely numbers, but that's clearly not what you want. (That's what your code does.)

---

I think you are trying to convert from *from* hex to chars.

```
6 chars "6a6b0a" ⇒ 3 chars "\x6a\x6b\x0a"
```

If so, you can use your choice of

```
$final =~ s/(..)/ chr(hex($1)) /seg;
```

or

```
$final = pack 'H*', $final;
```

---

The other possibility I can think of is that you want to unpack 16-bit integers.

```
6 chars "6a6b" ⇒ 13 chars "0x6136 0x6236"   (LE byte order)
   -or-
6 chars "6a6b" ⇒ 13 chars "0x3661 0x3662"   (BE byte order)
```

If so, you can use

```
my @nums = unpack 'S<*', $packed;  # For 16-bit ints, LE byte order
   -or-
my @nums = unpack 'S>*', $packed;  # For 16-bit ints, BE byte order

my $final = join ' ', map sprintf('0x%04X', $_), @nums;
```